# How to POST to admin-post.php from Avada formbuilder form

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Using the Avada theme's form builder functionality, I’m attempting to use the “Send to URL” option to POST the form and then run an api call in a plugin I’ve written.

I was thinking I could set the “Send to URL” value to /wp-admin/admin-post.php and add a hidden field to the form named “action” with a value of “make_api_call” to get it to run the code in my plugin set up like so:

```
add_action('admin_post_make_api_call', 'make_api_call');
function make_api_call()
{
    //todo: make the api call

    wp_redirect(‘another-page’);
}
```

However, this does not work and returns this from the server: `{"status":"error","info":"url_failed"}`

What I want to do is to POST the form to admin-post.php, have my plugin run code when it POSTs, and then redirect to another page.

I've checked the documentation for the AVADA theme and it only says that you can specify a url to post to but doesn't give any additional details.

Answer (score 2):

So I eventually got something to work, and I'm not knowledgeable or experienced enough with WordPress development to know if it is the "right" way, but it works well.

I realized that using the "Send to Url" option on the Avada form, it was POSTing the form to the `admin-ajax.php` file. There's plenty of documentation on that and I was able to partially make that work but I was not able to make it fit my use case b/c even though there is a way to configure the Avada form to redirect to a different URL on success I couldn't append parameters to that URL based on the return value from `admin-ajax.php`.

For future reference, here's what I was able to make work but not fit my use case by having the Avada form submission set to `Send to Url`.  (I'm recreating this and some of it's from memory since I went with a different solution, so it may not be 100% runnable.)

[image: Form set to Send to Url]

The way `admin-ajax` works is all requests to `admin-ajax.php` are eventually handled by a WordPress action (filter?) like so:
`add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_function' );`

In the above, `my_action` is what you've set as the form's `action` by creating a hidden input element on your html form named `action` and setting it's value to "my_action". The `my_function` argument is the name of the function you want to run when the action happens.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_function' );
function my_function(){
//do stuff
}
```

Watching the request in Chrome's dev tools, I could see the `action` the form was setting was `fusion_form_submit_form_to_url`.

[image: Dev tools]

So ended up with this:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_fusion_form_submit_form_to_url', 'my_function' );
function my_function(){
//do stuff
}
```

You can see that the url you enter in the `Form Submission URL` field gets passed to `admin-ajax` as `fusionAction`. Whether the Avada theme does something additional with that - I don't know but you could use it to control the logic that gets executed in `my_function`. I suspect there's an action in the Avada form that works similar to the `wp_ajax_` WordPress action but by the time I got this far I realized this wasn't going to work so I pivoted to the actual solution, below.

All of that worked okay but you can't redirect out of a call to admin-ajax.php unless you do it on the client side and I didn't want to dive into that.

What I was able to make work was configuring the Avada form to do a traditional `HTTP POST`. I added a hidden input element on the Avada form with a name of `formName` and the value set to the name of the form I wanted to handle.

[image: Avada Form]

In my plugin code, I hooked into the WordPress `init` action as in the code sample below, and then customized the logic to be executed based on which `formName` was sent in.

```
add_action('init', 'callback_function');
function callback_function()
{   
    if (isset($_POST['formName'])) {
        $form = $_POST['formName']; //from the hidden input element "formName"      
            
            //there is a call to wp_redirect in each case
            switch ($form) {
                case 'form1':                    
                    process_form_1();

                    break;
                case 'form2':
                    process_form_1();

                    break;

                default:
                    # code...
                    break;
            }
      
        //without this "exit" you will get errors similar to "headers already sent"
        exit;
    }
}
```

This allowed me to run the code I needed to run based on what form was submitted, and redirect to the correct place afterward.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to post data to form submission url please follow step by step process.

1. Step 1: Go to Avada form page in backend
   Example Url :- `https://www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=avada-forms`
2. Step 2: Edit any form you want to send data
3. Step 3: Go to form option
   3.1 click on Submission tab
   Set Submission Type : `AJAX`
   Action : select action to apply when form submit - `Send To URL`
   [please see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UcPGH.png)
4. Submission Method - Choose `Post` Option to send
5. Form Submission URL : Enter the URL where form data should be sent to

Example Url :- `https://www.yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=action_your_name`

Write a code in your active theme of `functions.php` file

```
add_action('wp_ajax_action_your_name', 'callback_function_name');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_action_your_name', 'callback_function_name');
 
function callback_function_name(){
    $data = $_REQUEST;
    $api_url    = 'your_api_url';
    $body       = array(
        'name' => $data['name'],        
        'email'=> $data['email'],
        'phone_number' => $data['phone_number'],
        'message' => $data['free_trial_message']
        
    );
    $args       = array(
        'body'    => $body,
    );
    $response = wp_remote_post($api_url, $args);
}
```

$data['name'],$data['email'] get from `field_types` key name in `admin-ajax` request
[see admin-ajax request field parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtp2m.png)